# how to "group" and pass data to a method that contains commas as a single value in an array in Groovy

Tags: arrays, rest, groovy

I'm have some Groovy code that will create test runs from data pulled in arrays such as,

```
def testRunTitle = ["Test Run Title 1", "Test Run Title 2"]
def testRunOutcome = ["Passed", "Failed"]
```

I'm hoping for some help on how to "group" and pass data to a method that contains commas as a single value in an array.

```
def testPoints = [("1372168","1372172","1372176"), ("1472169, 1472172, 1472176")]
```

so the create method in the first iteration will:

1. Create a test run called "Test run Title 1"
2. with an outcome of "Passed"
3. and using the first 3 test points "1372168","1372172","1372176"

I need the next iteration to:

1. Create test run called "Test run Title 2"
2. with an outcome of "Failed"
3. Using the second set of test points "1472169, 1472172, 1472176"

the method looks like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<RunIds.size(); i++) {
    def createTestRun = testManagementService.createTestRun(collection, Project, testRunTitle[i], testRunOutcome[i], testPoints[i])
}
```

I have to pass the test point values in this format in the post call to properly create the test run.  I can only pass the data in this format

"1372168","1372172","1372176"

I'm sure there's a way to format the data to do this but I'm still pretty new to Groovy and havent had much luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collate()` to do the trick for `testPoints`:

```
def testPoints = ["1372168","1372172","1372176", "1472169", "1472172", "1472176"]
testPoints = testPoint.collate 3


for(int i=0; i<RunIds.size(); i++) {
    println testPoints[i]
    def createTestRun = testManagementService.createTestRun(collection, Project, testRunTitle[i], testRunOutcome[i], testPoints[i])
}
```

would print the groups of 3 of testPoints List

Comment: Thanks for the help here.  I was able to get it working using the following syntax            `def testPoints = [["1372168","1372172","1372176"], ["1472169","1472172","1472176"]]
println(testPoints[i])`

Comment: thats essentially what collate() on a plain list does for you